# Simplifying UIImagePickerController

Tags: iphone, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm implementing Augmented Reality in my app. Is there anyway to just have a Cancel button, since taking pictures is out of the question? I know there's a similar question, but that is just overdoing it for me. I only wish to have the Cancel button, the rest can be hidden.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide the camera control and show your own overlay view using these 2 methods:

```
@property(nonatomic) BOOL showsCameraControls

@property(nonatomic, retain) UIView *cameraOverlayView
```

[More here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIImagePickerController/cameraOverlayView)

The overlayview is easy to implement. You only need to have a button "Cancel" there and handle the event to hide the UIImagePickerController